# VLOOKUP and match functions appear to be searching the function rather than value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Vlookup and match seem to be searching based on the function I have in my cell rather than the value i have in the cell. I have a column with dates, (ex: C2, which has the formula `=E2&"/"&F2&"/"&D2` in them, for example). (where E2, F2, D2 are the year, month, and date).

In another sheet and column, I have a bunch of dates, and i'm using the formula

`=VLOOKUP(C2,'sheet2'!A1:B252,2,FALSE),` which doesn't work. (returns `#N/A`)

If I replace `C2` with the same date, but without the formula (just typing it in), `VLOOKUP` works. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this formula

```
=E2&"/"&F2&"/"&D2
```

with this

```
=DATE(E2,F2,D2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For folks seeing this question and wondering why it happened (all that is left as this is a fine answer to the difficulty), the reason the problem occurred is that string functions produce TEXT results. So Brandon S was searching values (dates are stored as numbers in Excel) with text (since the formula produced a text representation of the date desired, not a numerical value which Excel could match to the numerical values being searched in.

(That's why the answer can't be bettered! It takes the same components and with even less characters makes them into a "real" date, into numerical values, not text.)